# From Gitbash to Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gruntjs

I have a function in my .bashrc file on Win7 that looks like this:

```
function gi() {
    npm install --save-dev grunt-"$@"
}
```

It allows me to type "gi (grunt plugin)" to quickly install a plugin.

I copied this .bashrc file over to Ubuntu and opening the terminal gives the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
```

What is the correct syntax for this function in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `function` with bash, so in your bashrc file, simply remove that word:

```
gi() {
    echo npm install --save-dev grunt-"$@"
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's useful to know, but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you still get exactly the same error?  I wonder if this is partly a line-ending problem; can't recall what the `\r` means, but could it be something to do with CRLF?

Answer (score 1):

You have a carriage return (\r) somewhere in there. Try simply retyping the whole thing in Ubuntu. Alternatively, you could just use delete or backspace to make it all one line, then hit "enter" a few times to make it look pretty in Ubuntu. The trick is to do that "enter" typing IN Ubuntu so you get Unix line feeds, not Windows ones.